# How do I export a function to be called in another file script

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, module, export

```js
> Here is the exported code
function start() {
  inquirer
    .prompt({
      name: "empChoice",
      type: "list",
      message: "What would you like to do?",
      choices: [
        "Employee View",
        "Department View",
        "Roles View",
        "Department View by salary totals",
        "Employee View by Managers",
        "Add Department",
        "Add Roles",
        "Add Employees",
        "Update Employee Roles",
        "Update Employee Managers",
        "Delete Departments",
        "Delete Roles",
        "Delete Employees",
        "Exit",
      ],
    })
    .then(function (answer) {
        switch (answer.empChoice) {
            case "Employee View":
             queryCalls.empFunc();
             break;
      
            case "Department View":
              queryCalls.deptFunc();
              break;
      
            case "Roles View":
              queryCalls.rolesView();
              break;
      
            case "Department View by salary totals":
              deptSalaryView();
              break;

            case "Employee View by Managers":
              empmanagerView();
              break;

            case "Add Department":
              addDept();
              break;

            case "Add Roles":
              addRoles();
              break;

            case "Add Employees":
              addEmployees();
              break;

            case "Update Employee Roles":
              updateEmployeeRoles();
              break;

            case "Update Employee Managers":
              updateEmployeeManagers();
              break;
      

            case "Delete Departments":
              delDept();
              break;

              case "Delete Roles":
              delRoles();
              break;

            case "Delete Employees":
              delEmployees();
              break;

            case "Exit":
              connection.end();
              break;
    }


    });
};
start();

export default start;



> Here is my code from the file where I want to import the code above: 

// Dependencies 
const options = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
host : '127.0.0.1',
user : 'root', // db user
password : 'password', // db password
database : 'employees_db' // db needed 
  }
};

const knex = require('knex') (options);

const cTable = require('console.table');


import start from "../app.js";


// exported functions
let queryCalls = {
  // function Employee View
  empFunc: function() {
knex.from('employee').select("*")
.then((output) => {
        console.log('\n');
        console.table(output);
    }
) 
.catch((err) => { console.log( err); throw err })
.finally(() => {
    knex.destroy();
})
start();
  };

> But I keep getting this error: 

(node:2393) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use 
 the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/somelinaobiechina/Desktop/EmployeeTracker/app.js:112
export default start;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'.
```

> I have tried all different modes of export but none has worked so far. I am currently stomped :(.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ES 5 syntax..

```
function start(){
 ....
}

function play(){
  ...
}

module.exports = start //default export

module.exports = {
 play
} // name export
```

and import it

```
const start = require('../app.js')

const { play } = require('../app.js')
```